# Oraclize a restfullAPI using a specific number represented by the variable z

Tags: truffle, dapp-development, dapps, oracles, ganache

Hello I made a restfull API on my own (python file jsonify + localtunnel) on a localhost using a specific number (in this case 141) represented by the variable z. This variable should go into DevCoin function balances[msg.sender] and should be displayed on localhost:8080 as: You have 141 DVC. For this purpose I use ganache-cli (Listening on 127.0.0.1:8545) , ethereum-bridge(node bridge -a 9 -H 127.0.0.1 -p 8545 --dev) as well as truffle.js (8545). Using: truffle compile, truffle migrate --development --reset and npm run dev leading to no error. The problem is now, when I connect the index.html(where my variable should be displayed) with a private network on metamask on localhost:8545, I got: You have 0 DVC. I don't know why. If I pass instead of z a number, the chosen number is displayed. Have anyone any idea to help me out?[image][image]enter image description here[image: ethereum-bridge "result":"141"][image: RestAPI]
Truffle console:
[image]

App.js
[image]
[image]

truffle.js
[image]

2_deploy_contracts.js
[image]

index.html
[image]

Comment: As you can see via the bridge output, the Oraclize setup is working correctly and returning the `z` of 141 to your smart contract. 

So to figure out your issue, first I would use the Truffle console to access your contract on this test-net and query it directly to confirm that `z` is infact updated to `141`.

Then, when you've confirmed that, you'll know that the problem is with the front-end side of your DApp. At that point we can't help further until you post the javascript code that you're using to access the smart-contract.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

#### Meta:

- You should edit your original question to include the screenshots that you have mistakenly posted as a reply.
- You should refrain from posting *images* of code, and post the actual code instead. Code cannot be copy & pasted from images making it much more work for an answerer to type out a reply.

---

### Answer:

Your issue is that in the `javascript`, when the balance is refreshed it is querying `account[0]`'s *balance*, whereas you are hoping to retrieve the `z` *value* from your smart contract.

So to fix this you have two options:

#### Option 1:

- Change the *javascript* to query the smart-contract for the `z` variable

#### Option 2:

- Change the *smart-contact* to apportion the result of the `Oraclize` query as a balance for `account[0]`.

---

### Code:

An issue with **Option 2** is that you'll need to know the address of `account[0]` before hand, and hard code it into your contract. This isn't ideal, so we'll go for **Option 1** instead.

Find the `refreshBalance` function in `App.js` and change the line:

> return dev.getBalance.call(account, {from: account});

To read:

> return dev.z.call();

Now it'll be querying the `z` variable, and returning the result to the balance `span` in the html.

#### Note

The `Oraclize` query is *asynchronous*, so please make sure the `refreshBalance` javascript function is called *after* the Oraclize query has returned, or else your the value will remain `0`.

---

### Edit - Answering follow-up question:

The `sendCoin` functionality should *already* work, looking at the code. However, looking at the smart-contract, no account ends up *owning* any of the coin in order to send any. The `constructor` function gives the deployer (`[msg.sender]`) an amount of coins equal to `z`. However the contract begins life with `z = 0`, and so ∴ `msg.sender` also has none.

To rectify this, change the line:

> balances[msg.sender] = z;

to:

> balances[msg.sender] = 1000000;

Congratulations! `[msg.sender]`, who in this case is Truffle `account[0]`, has a million DVC! Now when you use the `send` functionality in your DApp, you'll have some coins to send!

Comment: wow thank you very much. It works for the refreshBalance function. How would you change the the sendCoin function, to send some DVC? Greets

Comment: Please accept the answer so other used can know that it provides an accurate solution. As for your other question, I'll edit the answer now...

Comment: Ok I have done it!

Comment: Also, could you add the images you posted in your _answer_, into your question, so that other users can see the full code of your question in one single post? That'd make things much clearer for anyone else experiencing similar issues to yourself! Many thanks!

Comment: No problem & thanks for reorganising your question so now other people can understand the question & answer together!